# Zend_Form not showing error message

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have the following ZF form element.

```
    $this->addElement('text', 'price', array(
        'required'  => true,
        'label'     => 'Price:',
        'attribs'   => array(
            'title'     => 'Please enter the value of your artwork'),
        'filters'   => array('Currency'),
        'validators'    => array(
            array('NotEmpty', true, array(
                'messages' => array(
                    Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY =>
                        "You must enter your artworks price"))),
            array('Float', true, array(
                'messages'  => array(
                    Zend_Validate_Float::INVALID => 
                        "You must enter a valid price",
                    Zend_Validate_Float::NOT_FLOAT =>
                        "You must enter a valid price"))),
            array('GreaterThan', true, array(
                'min'   => 0.99,
                'messages'  => array(
                    Zend_Validate_GreaterThan::NOT_GREATER =>
                        "You must enter a value of £1.00 or more"))))
    ));
```

The last validator is Zend_Validate_GreaterThan which has been set an error message, my problem is that the error message is not displayed on the form when this validator fails. All I get rendered is an empty unordered list!!

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

When I check the messages output by zend_form I get the error and the message.

```
array(1) {
  ["price"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["notGreaterThan"]=>
    string(39) "You must enter a value of £1.00 or more"
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why the message is not being rendered on the form?

Many thanks in advance

Garry

EDIT

The only decorator I am using is a viewscript to render the form, on the form I have.

```
$this->setDecorators(array(
    array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'forms/add-item.phtml'))
));
```

and the viewscript itself.

```
$attribFilterObj = new Freedom_Zend_Filter_HtmlAttribs();
$attribs = $attribFilterObj->filter($this->element->getAttribs());
?>
<form <?php echo $attribs; ?>>
<dl>
    <?php echo $this->element->ArtworkTitle->title->render(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->element->ArtworkDescription->description->render(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->element->price->render(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->element->Genres->render(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->element->image->render(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->element->add->render(); ?>
</dl>
</form>
```

EDIT

The output of the var_dump is as follows

```
array(5) {
  ["Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewHelper"]=>
  object(Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewHelper)#157 (6) {
    ["_buttonTypes":protected]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(24) "Zend_Form_Element_Button"
      [1]=>
      string(23) "Zend_Form_Element_Reset"
      [2]=>
      string(24) "Zend_Form_Element_Submit"
    }
    ["_helper":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_placement":protected]=>
    string(6) "APPEND"
    ["_element":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_options":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_separator":protected]=>
    string(2) "
"
  }
  ["Zend_Form_Decorator_Errors"]=>
  object(Zend_Form_Decorator_Errors)#158 (4) {
    ["_placement":protected]=>
    string(6) "APPEND"
    ["_element":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_options":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_separator":protected]=>
    string(2) "
"
  }
  ["Zend_Form_Decorator_Description"]=>
  object(Zend_Form_Decorator_Description)#159 (6) {
    ["_escape":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_placement":protected]=>
    string(6) "APPEND"
    ["_tag":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_element":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_options":protected]=>
    array(2) {
      ["tag"]=>
      string(1) "p"
      ["class"]=>
      string(11) "description"
    }
    ["_separator":protected]=>
    string(2) "
"
  }
  ["Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag"]=>
  object(Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag)#160 (7) {
    ["_encoding":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_placement":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_tag":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_tagFilter":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_element":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_options":protected]=>
    array(2) {
      ["tag"]=>
      string(2) "dd"
      ["id"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["callback"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(22) "Zend_Form_Element_Text"
          [1]=>
          string(16) "resolveElementId"
        }
      }
    }
    ["_separator":protected]=>
    string(2) "
"
  }
  ["Zend_Form_Decorator_Label"]=>
  object(Zend_Form_Decorator_Label)#161 (6) {
    ["_placement":protected]=>
    string(7) "PREPEND"
    ["_tag":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_tagClass":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_element":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_options":protected]=>
    array(1) {
      ["tag"]=>
      string(2) "dt"
    }
    ["_separator":protected]=>
    string(2) "
"
  }
}
```

Comment: I copied the form code you provided and added it to a test form and I was able to see the error message about the price rendered correctly.  What decorators are being used for that element, anything special?

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for your response.  The only decorator I am using is a viewscript. Please see my edit above.

Comment: What are the standard element decorators added to `Zend_Form_Element`s?  I see you render the form using the ViewScript decorator, but each element uses its own set of decorators to render.  Chances are whatever it is using doesn't have the `Errors` decorator.  You can try `var_dump($this->element->price->getDecorators());` to see what they are.

Comment: Hi Drew, I have added the output of your var_dump above.  The errors decorator is there.

Comment: The problem is probably due to the `Currency` filter you have; what does that do?  If you remove it do you get the error message?

Answer (score 1):

This is sometimes caused by forgetting to include 'Errors' in the form decorator for the element. If you're using a custom decorator, check that first.

Comment: Hi NaNuk, Thanks for your response.  As I have just mentioned to Drew above the only decorator I am using is a viewscript, please see my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

a bit old but check this site http://zendguru.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/handling-zend-framework-form-error-messages/

i believe you have to get the error messages yourselve like and then print them

```
$errorsMessages = $this->form->getMessages();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I was only using a ViewScript as you are. This solved it:

```
($this is in the form class I created)
$this->setDecorators(array(
        array('ViewScript', 
              array('viewScript' => '/formElementViewscripts/editRoughDraft/_form.phtml')),
        'Form'
    ));
```

You must also add the default 'Form' decorator to your form if you want to be able to receive those messages. I tried looking through the code but I couldn´t pinpoint exactly why.