# ZF 1.12 Zend_Form won´t display Form_Elements error messages without default 'Form' decorator, how come?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I stumbled on to a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901683/zend-form-not-showing-error-message/16868521#16868521) (if not to say the same). At first I only had set my form decorator to be my custom ViewScript where I displayed my elements, very simple and straight. But when time came to "submit", no errors showed even though I clearly set errors in the inputs.

In order for my messages to display (in order for my form to actually get the messages, because

```
$this->element->element_name->getMessages()
```

was giving me nothing) I had to add the default 'Form' decorator to my Form's decorators, ending up with two: the custom ViewScript and the Form.

I tried looking through the code of 'Form' decorator, but couldn´t pinpoint why this was happening. I was wondering if anyone knew, because I'd like to learn.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is very useful document to trace and solve your error.

i think this [LINK](http://www.mwop.net/blog/217-Creating-composite-elements.html) would be very useful to you to make things working at your end. just read and try to understand carefully

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: It's a good article if you want to build up your own Form_Element to be used like any other default Form_Element (including view helpers and all), but it was not able to answer my question.